# Rust, diesel: load type parameter not compatible

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I am trying to make a simple query for users that match the given credentials using diesel.
From reading the diesel docs I think that I need to use the Queryable macro on the struct I will use on load, but I get an error for Incompatible types

When I run the program I get the following error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `(Integer, Text, Text, Text, diesel::sql_types::Timestamp): load_dsl::private::CompatibleType<dal::models::users::UserView<'_>, _>` is not satisfied
    --> src/services/user.rs:16:27
     |
16   |         .load::<UserView>(connection);
     |          ----             ^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `load_dsl::private::CompatibleType<dal::models::users::UserView<'_>, _>` is not implemented for `(Integer, Text, Text, Text, diesel::sql_types::Timestamp)`
     |          |
     |          required by a bound introduced by this call
     |
     = help: the following other types implement trait `load_dsl::private::CompatibleType<U, DB>`:
               (ST0, ST1)
               (ST0, ST1, ST2)
               (ST0, ST1, ST2, ST3)
               (ST0, ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4)
               (ST0, ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4, ST5)
               (ST0, ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4, ST5, ST6)
               (ST0, ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4, ST5, ST6, ST7)
               (ST0, ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4, ST5, ST6, ST7, ST8)
             and 24 others
     = note: required for `SelectStatement<FromClause<table>, DefaultSelectClause<FromClause<table>>, NoDistinctClause, WhereClause<Grouped<And<Grouped<Eq<username, ...>>, ...>>>>` to implement `LoadQuery<'_, _, dal::models::users::UserView<'_>>`
     = note: the full type name has been written to '/home/pop/Documents/code/PECI-05-2022-23/auth/target/debug/deps/auth-955be7812e7a3b43.long-type-7337842634617248670.txt'
note: required by a bound in `diesel::RunQueryDsl::load`
    --> /home/pop/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/diesel-2.0.3/src/query_dsl/mod.rs:1499:15
     |
1499 |         Self: LoadQuery<'query, Conn, U>,
     |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `RunQueryDsl::load`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `dal::models::users::UserView<'_>: FromSqlRow<_, _>` is not satisfied
    --> src/services/user.rs:16:27
     |
16   |         .load::<UserView>(connection);
     |          ----             ^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `FromSqlRow<_, _>` is not implemented for `dal::models::users::UserView<'_>`
     |          |
     |          required by a bound introduced by this call
     |
     = help: the following other types implement trait `FromSqlRow<ST, DB>`:
               <(T1, T0) as FromSqlRow<(ST1, Untyped), __DB>>
               <(T1, T2, T0) as FromSqlRow<(ST1, ST2, Untyped), __DB>>
               <(T1, T2, T3, T0) as FromSqlRow<(ST1, ST2, ST3, Untyped), __DB>>
               <(T1, T2, T3, T4, T0) as FromSqlRow<(ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4, Untyped), __DB>>
               <(T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T0) as FromSqlRow<(ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4, ST5, Untyped), __DB>>
               <(T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T0) as FromSqlRow<(ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4, ST5, ST6, Untyped), __DB>>
               <(T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T0) as FromSqlRow<(ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4, ST5, ST6, ST7, Untyped), __DB>>
               <(T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T0) as FromSqlRow<(ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4, ST5, ST6, ST7, ST8, Untyped), __DB>>
             and 23 others
     = note: required for `SelectStatement<FromClause<table>, DefaultSelectClause<FromClause<table>>, NoDistinctClause, WhereClause<Grouped<And<Grouped<Eq<username, ...>>, ...>>>>` to implement `LoadQuery<'_, _, dal::models::users::UserView<'_>>`
     = note: the full type name has been written to '/home/pop/Documents/code/PECI-05-2022-23/auth/target/debug/deps/auth-955be7812e7a3b43.long-type-7337842634617248670.txt'
note: required by a bound in `diesel::RunQueryDsl::load`
    --> /home/pop/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/diesel-2.0.3/src/query_dsl/mod.rs:1499:15
     |
1499 |         Self: LoadQuery<'query, Conn, U>,
     |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `RunQueryDsl::load`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
warning: `auth` (bin "auth") generated 3 warnings
error: could not compile `auth` (bin "auth") due to 2 previous errors; 3 warnings emitted
```

This is my login function:

```
pub fn login(user_credentials: UserLogin) -> bool {
    use crate::dal::schema::users::dsl::*;
    let connection = &mut get_connection();
    let result = users
        .filter(username.eq(user_credentials.username))
        .filter(password.eq(user_credentials.password))
        .load::<UserView>(connection);

    match result {
        Ok(query_res) => return query_res.len() == 1,
        Err(_) => return false
    }
}
```

This is the struct I'm using with load

```
#[derive(Queryable)]
pub struct UserView<'a> {
    pub user_id: i32,
    pub username: &'a str,
    pub email: &'a str,
    pub created_on: SystemTime
}
```

And this is my users schema:

```
diesel::table! {
    users (user_id) {
        user_id -> Int4,
        username -> Varchar,
        password -> Varchar,
        email -> Varchar,
        created_on -> Timestamp,
    }
}
```

Finally, my Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "auth"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
rocket = { version = "0.5.0-rc.2", features= ["json"]}
diesel = { version = "2.0.1", features = ["postgres", "chrono"] }
dotenv = "0.15.0"
chrono = "^0"
serde = { version = "1.0.117", features = ["derive"] }
serde_json = "1.0.59"
```

## Update

Changing my UserView class to:

```
#[derive(Queryable)]
pub struct UserView {
    pub user_id : i32,
    pub username : String,
    pub password : String,
    pub email: String,
    pub created_on: SystemTime,
}
```

solved the issue, i thought you could select the fields you wanted with load, which was my mistake

Comment: your types aren't the same;  your table has a `password` field that isn't in your `UserView`.  with 3 text fields in your `users` and only two in your `UserView`, there is no way to infer which one to omit from the mapping.  from the error, `the trait bound '(Integer, Text, Text, Text, diesel::sql_types::Timestamp): load_dsl::private::CompatibleType<dal::models::users::UserView<'_>, _>' is not satisfied`, diesel expects your `UserView` to have 3 Text fields.

Comment: I have tryed adding the passord field as type &'a str but i get the same problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Experiencing a "CompatibleType<Attachment, Sqlite> not implemented" error when filtering by ID on a passed-in connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75700125/experiencing-a-compatibletypeattachment-sqlite-not-implemented-error-when-f)

Comment: @Claies changing "&'a str" to "String" and adding the password field as you said solved the issue :)

I don't know how to close the question but thanks a lot!